# Использование wildcard  в Generics Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

Вот решил немного поглубже изучить *Generic*, так как возникла потребность написать свой класс. Раньше как-то не обращал внимание, а сейчас хочу разобраться.
Проблема в том, что не могу понять суть использования `<T super SomeClass>`. Читал много литературы, но все-таки не понял.

Есть еще одна противоположная wildcard - `<T extends SomeClass>`. С этим все очевидно. Мощная концепция. У нас есть суперкласс, в моем случае `SomeClass`. Может быть и интерфейс. Но тут неважно. У него есть свои методы. Которые обязательно будут! Не важно, сколько раз был унаследован и какие методы добавил. Нам важно, что мы уверены в том, что у любого наследника класса будут методы суперкласса, и нам все равно, как называется класс-наследник, просто вызываем методы, и все. Тут все ясно.

НО вот `<T super SomeClass>` что-то совсем не понятно, какие преимущества предоставляет. Я понимаю, что это противоположная вещь `<T extends SomeClass>`, то есть просто один *wildcard* ограничивает сверху, другая снизу. Непонятно, зачем это использовать.

Читал про концепцию PECS. Примеры смотрел, но так и не понял.

Какой нам толк от того, что переданный класс будет суперклассом `SomeClass`. Ну, допустим, `Object`->`ParentSomeClass`->`SomeClass` будет такая иерархия. Ну, все классы валидно передадутся, и не будет compiler error. НО какой от этого толк? Я могу реализовать любые методы и в `ParentSomeClass`, и в `SomeClass`. Допустим, в `ParentSomeClass` не будет методов, которые есть в `SomeClass`. А в `Object`, естественно, не будет методов, которые реализовал `ParentSomeClass`. И какой тогда толк, одни проблемы.

Читал, что это используется, когда нужно добавлять элементы, в коллекцию, например. Но все-таки не понял сути.

Пожалуйста, объясните, как можно подробнее.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Чтобы понять мнемонику **PECS** (*provider - extends, consumer - super*), рассмотрим в качестве конкретного примера статический метод из стандартного класса `Collections`:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

Этот метод копирует список типа `Т` в другой список. Он использует сразу оба вида ограничений: сверху для целевого списка и снизу для источника.

Начнем с источника. Источником могут быть любые дочерние от `T` типы. Это логично, нас не интересует, что именно мы перекладываем, нужно, чтобы оно хотя бы сводилось к T. `src` является для нас поставщиком (*producer*) объектов, и его тип мы позволяем расширять (*extends*). Это первые 2 буквы из мнемоники **PECS**.

Теперь перейдем к целевому списку. В дальнейшем этим списком кто-то будет пользоваться и, возможно, как-то его обрабатывать, и это накладывает определенные ограничения. Проще посмотреть это на примере.

Предположим, что у нас есть класс `Питомцев` (являющийся подклассом `Животных`) и дочерние классы `Собачонок` и `Котиков`:

```
class Animal { void feed() {} }
class Pet extends Animal { void call() {} }
class Kitty extends Pet{ void mew() {} }
class Doge extends Pet{ void bark() {} }
```

Теперь мы хотим скопировать из списка `Питомцев` в список `Питомцев` и `позвать` их.

```
List<Pet> src = ...;
List<Pet> dest = new ArrayList<Pet>();    
Collections.copy(dest, src);
for(Pet p: dest) p.call();
```

Пока все ок. А что если бы в `src` были явно `Котики` (унаследованные от `Питомцев`)?

```
List<Kitty> src = ...;
List<Pet> dest = new ArrayList<Pet>();    
Collections.copy(dest, src);
for(Pet p: dest) p.call();
```

Без проблем, `Котики` откликаются на зов. При копировании в `dest` мы "потеряем" знание о том, что это были именно `Котики`, но по крайней мере они остаются `Питомцами` и их все еще можно позвать.

Достаточно очевидно, что мы не можем скопировать `Котиков` в коллекцию `Собачонок` и заставить их всех `лаять`:

```
List<Kitty> src = ...;
List<Doge> dest = new ArrayList<Doge>();    
Collections.copy(dest, src);
for(Doge doge: dest) doge.bark();
```

Очевидный нонсенс, `Котиков` нельзя просто грубо назвать `Собачонками`, система типов не позволит так сделать, поэтому мы не смогли бы расширить тип первого параметра в сигнатуре метода `copy`:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? extends T> dest, List<? extends T> src); // так нельзя копировать!
```

Но что же насчет `super`? Пусть наш код продолжит копировать `Питомцев`, а где-то в другом место другой код кормит любых `Животных`, и не только домашних.

```
List<Animal> dest = new ArrayList<Animal>();   
.....
List<Kitty> src = ...;
Collections.<Pet>copy(dest, src);
....
for(Animal a: dest) a.feed();
```

Все `Животные` накормлены. Заметим, что целевой список является коллекцией `Животных`, являющихся родительским классом для `Питомцев`. Общая концепция такова, что код, который использует в дальнейшем список `dest`, не может в своих предположениях о его элементах опускаться ниже типа `T`, но может сколь угодно абстрагироваться к родительским типам. Список `dest` является потребителем (*consumer*), т.к. мы наполняем его и знаем, только, что его элементы совместимы с `T`, а значит сами являются `T` или лежат выше по иерархии (*super*). Это последние две буквы в мнемонике **PECS**.

Надеюсь, что-то прояснил для вас.

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!!
___

Ох, все равно что-то туго, а если у нас не будет у класса, который мы положили в dest, метода feed?

Comment: > а если у нас не будет у класса который мы положили в dest метода feed

а куда ж он денется? мы кладем в `dest` гарантировано потомка `Т`. А раз у `T` есть `feed`, то и у потомка он есть.

Comment: То есть использование super дает преимущества, при использовании в связке с extends ? А если отдельно использовать, то он бесполезен ?

Comment: А если отдельно, то бесполезно ложить в один список котят и столы, а потом пытаться всех накормить.