# В чем разница между `List<someType>` и `List<? extends someType>`?

Tags: java, generics

Коллекция `List<someType>` (как и `List<? extends someType>`) позволит мне добавлять элементы порожденных классов от someType.
`List<? extends someType>` (как и `List<someType>`) будет возвращать элемент типа someType при вызове метода get().

В чем же между ними разница?

Comment: Рекомендую заглянуть в похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361807

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Классы `Double` и `Integer` наследуется от `Number`.

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>();

public static void doSomething1(List<? extends Number> list) {
    // ...
}

public static void doSomething2(List<Number> list) {
    // ...
}

doSomething1(numberList);  // ok
doSomething1(doubleList);  // ok
doSomething1(integerList); // ok

doSomething2(numberList);  // ok
doSomething2(doubleList);  // ошибка компиляции
doSomething2(integerList); // ошибка компиляции
```

Еще пример:

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubleList.add(1.2);

List<Number> numberList = doubleList; // ошибка компиляции
List<Number> numberList = (List<Number>) doubleList; // ошибка компиляции
List<? extends Number> numberList = doubleList; // ok

Number number = numberList.get(0); // 1.2
```

Answer (score 9):

Положим, что `DerivedType extends BaseType`. В таком случае `List<DerivedType>` является подтипом `List<? extends BaseType>`, но не является подтипом `List<BaseType>`.

Когда вы объявляете переменную типа `List<SomeType>`, вы говорите, что список содержит или `SomeType`, или производные от него. Вы можете положить в список переменную любого типа, унаследованного от `SomeType` или самого его.

Когда вы объявляете переменную типа `List<? extends SomeType>`, вы говорите, какой тип списка переменная может содержать. Вы не можете просто взять и положить элемент типа `SomeType` в такую переменную, потому что с точки зрения компилятора список может оказаться и списком `List<DerivedType>`.

См. [Generics : `List<? extends Animal>` is same as `List<Animal>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal)