# Что значит <T extends SomeCreatedClass>, и зачем оно?

Tags: java

Есть следующая конструкция

```
 protected  <T extends SomeCreatedClass> void send(T message) throws Exception {
    //Some code
}
```

Что значит `<T extends SomeCreatedClass>`, и зачем оно?
когда я визиваю метод я пишу `send(someMessage)`.
И как мне написать метод, чтобы я мог вызивать `send<DataType>(someMessage)`?

```
SomeCreatedClass , `DataType`, Придумание класи для примера.
```

*Я только учусь.*

Comment: Вы совсем не знакомы с _обобщениями_ или только с ограниченными подстановочными типами?

Comment: Я читал про дженерики, но ето насколько я понял Клас которий принимает конкретний тип данних, а с обобщениями нет, или просто не понимаю о чем вы

Comment: Дженерики - это и есть обобщения. `<T extends SomeCreatedClass>` - это дженерик с ограниченным параметром типа.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду читать статейки, про то что вы написали

Comment: Лучше читайте учебники. Для начинающего важно получать информацию в систематизированном виде.

Comment: У Шилдта хорошо описана эта тема!

Comment: Тоесть в метод мы можем передать параметр только конкретного типа?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/361843/204271